# Transition Text On Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I like to make a very minimal and simple Index page in which I will have a white HTML page, and a text in the middle text will be

```
                               USEStudio
```

Then On Mouse Hover it would change to  :

```
                         UrbanSpaceEvent.Studio
```

and I like to link the second text to the website

I already tried some CSS codes but I couldn't add fade in fade out features and when I add the link it doesn't work

Comment: show us the code you've tried?

Comment: Think you have to use JavaScript to achieve that. But, yes... give the code you use

Comment: You can achieve this using css ::after psedo, check my anwser hope it helped

Comment: Hi, the 2 versions (see my answer) that are not pure CSS don't work properly yet under specific edge cases of user interaction; if you need to fix it and know how - just leave a comment :)

Comment: Apologies for typo in my commet above. I meant: "if you need to fix it and **don't** know how - just leave a comment"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to toggle visibility

*CSS only*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>stackoverflow.com</title>
    <style>
        .wrap{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .wrap:hover .state--off {
            display: block;
        }
        .wrap:hover .state--on,
        .state--off {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="YourLinkGoesHere" class="wrap">
        <p class="state--on">USEStudio</p>
        <p class="state--off">UrbanSpaceEvent.Studio</p>
    </a>
```

## You also want to add fade in & fade out - right?

*quick and dirty | the jQuery way*

```js
(function($) {
  var toggleState = function( domWrap, sClass ) {
    $Children = $( domWrap ).children();
    var $Hidden  = $Children.filter(':hidden'),
        $Visible = $Children.filter(':visible');
    $.when(
      $Visible.animate({opacity: 0})
    ).then(function(){
      $Visible.hide();
      $Hidden
        .css({display: 'block', opacity: 0})
        .animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow');
    })
  };
  $(function() { // document ready
    $('.wrap')
      .mouseenter(function(){ toggleState( this ) })
      .mouseleave(function(){ toggleState( this ) })
  })
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.wrap{
    text-align: center;
}

.state--off {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>stackoverflow.com</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="YourLinkGoesHere" class="wrap">
        <p class="state--on">USEStudio</p>
        <p class="state--off">UrbanSpaceEvent.Studio</p>
    </a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or you maybe want to use this fancy library called

## Animate.css

*CSS animation with jQuery as fallback*

https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

```js
(function($) {

    // choose from https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ and customize this script
    var sClassIn  = 'zoomIn',    // <- your string here //////////////////
        sClassOut = 'rotateOut'; // <- your string here //////////////////

    sClassIn  += ' animated';
    sClassOut += ' animated';

    var sAnimationEnd = (function() {
        var t,
            el = document.createElement('fakeelement'),
            animations = {
                'animation': 'animationend',
                'OAnimation': 'oAnimationEnd',
                'MozAnimation': 'animationend',
                'WebkitAnimation': 'webkitAnimationEnd'
            }

        for (t in animations) {
            if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
                return animations[t];
            }
        }
    })();

    var toggleState = function(domWrap, sClass) {
        $Children = $(domWrap).children();
        var $Hidden = $Children.filter(':hidden'),
            $Visible = $Children.filter(':visible');

        if (sAnimationEnd) { // modern browsers css animation
            var $Deferred = $.Deferred();
            $Visible.attr('class', sClassOut).one(
                sAnimationEnd,
                function() {
                    $Visible.hide().attr('class', '');
                    $Hidden.show().attr('class', sClassIn);
                    $Deferred.resolve();
                }
            );
            return $Deferred.promise();
        } else { // fallback | js animation
            return $.when( $Visible.animate({ opacity: 0 }) ).then(function() {
                $Visible.hide();
                $Hidden.show().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 'slow');
            });
        }

    };

    $(function() { // document ready
        $('.wrap')
            .mouseenter(function() { toggleState(this) })
            .mouseleave(function() { toggleState(this) })
    })

})(jQuery)
```

```css
.body, html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>stackoverflow.com</title>
    <style></style>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="YourLinkGoesHere" class="wrap">
        <p>USEStudio</p>
        <p style="display:none">UrbanSpaceEvent.Studio</p>
    </a>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want with pure css without javascript

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .hover_text:after {
      content: attr(data-nothovertext);
  }
  .hover_text:hover:after {
      content: attr(data-hovertext);
  }
  .hover_text {
      text-align: center;
        display:block;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#link_to_your_url" class="hover_text" data-hovertext="UrbanSpaceEvent.Studio" data-nothovertext="USEStudio" ></a>

</body>
</html>
```